# Changing Vaadin application to use secure websocket connection

Tags: java, websocket, vaadin, weblogic12c, vaadin7

I have an old Vaadin 7.7 application that is hosted on a Weblogic Oracle Application Server 12c application server.

This is a quite old app where I have access to the source code to change it.

Due to some network issues, it is needed to change the Vaadin application to use only Secure Websocket connections.

I was scanning the application configuration and the documentation of the Vaadin 7.7 but I can't simply find it where to enable this feature, to only use secure Websocket (wss://) connections.

Is Vaadin 7.7 capable of doing so? If so, how to turn on this configuration?

Comment: I think it still needs https for some parts. And when you use htts it should also use wss: instead of ws:

Comment: @AndréSchild: Is there anywhere a description about that? actually I don't know when it does use ws and when it keeps xhr(ajax) for communication.

Comment: Vaadin is using athmosphere under the hood to chosse the best communication channel. http://async-io.org/ It does some autodetection what possibilites exist, since for example proxies usually break websockets etc.